# why my script does not display the weather

Tags: javascript, html

I created a script to display the weather on my site, my problem when I execute it displays nothing.

this is my script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Weather API Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/html" id="weather_tmpl">
    <div class="weather_wrapper">
        <div class="top_wrapper top_wrapper_e">
            {{=day0}}
            <div class="bt_control" id="meteo_controller">
                <a href="javascript://">
                    <img src="arrow_open.png" id="meteo_trigger_img" width="27" height="17" alt="Arrow" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom_wrapper" id="meteo_future_days">
            <div class="next_days_wrapper">
                <div class="day first">
                    {{=day1}}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="day">
                    {{=day2}}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="day last">
                    {{=day3}}
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="detail_tmpl">
    <div class="date">{{=date.weekday}},
        <br />{{=date.day}} {{=monthname_short}}.</div>
    <div class="temp">{{=high.celsius}}</div>
    <div class="icon">
        <img src="{{=icon_url}}" width="34" height="34" alt="icone" />
    </div>
</script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="t.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    (function(){
        var mainTpl = new t($('#weather_tmpl').html()),
            detailTpl = new t($('#detail_tmpl').html());

 $.getJSON('http://api.wunderground.com/api/2ea138a9dd52eabe/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json')
            .done(function(data){
                var tplData = {};
                $.each(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday, function(index, day){
                    tplData['day'+index] = detailTpl.render(day);
                });
                $('body').append(mainTpl.render(tplData));
            });
    })();
</script>
    <script>
          var meteostatus = 0; // closed
          $('#meteo_controller').click(function() {
          if (meteostatus == 0) {
          meteostatus = 1;
          $('#meteo_future_days').fadeIn('slow');
          $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src', $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src').replace('open', 'close'));
          } else {
          meteostatus = 0;
          $('#meteo_future_days').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src', $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src').replace('close', 'open'));
          }
          });
         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS:

The data for the current day, and the forecast for the next 3 are in the array data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday.

I've used a templating library called t.js which you can find [here](https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js)

have a nice day

Comment: `t` is not defined.  Also, use `===` to compare with 0.  For all those people out there, a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7c7RS/)

Comment: you want us to download a library to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @EdHeal I figured out what was wrong with `try` and `catch`

Comment: can you enlighten a little bit

Comment: @ManofSnow - i am old fashioned and do not like to be asked to download software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the two of your `scripts` (the one with the id of `library` and the one with `t.min.js`) with:

```
<script src="https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js/blob/master/t.min.js" />
<script type="https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js/blob/master/template" id="test">
(function(){
        var mainTpl = new t($('#weather_tmpl').html()),
            detailTpl = new t($('#detail_tmpl').html());

 $.getJSON('http://api.wunderground.com/api/2ea138a9dd52eabe/forecast/q/CA/San_Francisco.json')
            .done(function(data){
                var tplData = {};
                $.each(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday, function(index, day){
                    tplData['day'+index] = detailTpl.render(day);
                });
                $('body').append(mainTpl.render(tplData));
            });
    })();
          var meteostatus = 0; // closed
          $('#meteo_controller').click(function() {
          if (meteostatus === 0) {
          meteostatus = 1;
          $('#meteo_future_days').fadeIn('slow');
          $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src', $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src').replace('open', 'close'));
          } else {
          meteostatus = 0;
          $('#meteo_future_days').fadeOut('slow');
          $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src', $('#meteo_trigger_img').attr('src').replace('close', 'open'));
          }
          });

</script>
```

You tried to put a script src as a local path on your server, where the file is being hosted on github.

Also, there is a script error.

Comment: thank you for response, but you have not answered my question, my problem I want to display the weather on my site, and the script displays nothing.

Comment: what should I do to get the weather on my site using this script ? and thank you

Comment: where is I can find the ID of the library

Comment: @b.mounaime There is a script error, I just found.

Comment: I want to display the weather on my site as [link](http://calypsopark.com) using this script, please can you help me .

Comment: @b.mounaime Try this script: `<div id="res"></div>
<script>
function weather(o){
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML="current temperature in Atlanta, Georgia is "+o.query.results.channel.item.condition.temp+" degrees farenheit."
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2230341%22&format=json&callback=weather"></script>`

Comment: @b.mounaime Any time.